# How to restrict user to click a button only one time in his machine

Tags: jquery, html, cookies, cross-browser

I'am making page for voting ,any user can vote without login.
user can only vote one time , so if user refresh the page the vote button must not appeared.

I try to save if user vote in cookies , 
but there is problem : user can re-vote if he opens another browser or remove cookies.

so how can prevent user from re-vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can never be entirely sure a user only votes once. What you can do is add multiple checks. Like store the IP-address of the user and check if that ip has already been used for voting. You could also require the voter to create an account on your website for which they'll need to verify their email address, and only allow a logged in user to vote once.

Comment: if i save IP address . IPs can be dynamic , and if we have internal IPs like in company in this way I will prevent all employees in company from voting ,isn't it?

Comment: @doha that's correct, the only way to make sure someone only votes once is to have them create an account, which you verify manually (by checking something like passports. Most of the time having someone create an account with an unique email address will suffice. But as you know anyone can create an infinite number of email addresses.

PS: Someone can also 'spoof' an IP-address by using a proxy of VPN

Answer (score 0):

If the user isn't anonymous, don't load the HTML for button in his view. The first time (before the user clicks it), show it, then as soon as he clicks it, save a flag for that user and then test for that flag when determining whether to render the button. Also make sure you remove the button from the DOM as soon as you get a success response from ajax (presuming you're doing it via ajax).
If the user is anonymous, then you can't really make a foolproof solution. One option would be to use browser fingerprinting and IP to try and limit that, but it's never going to be foolproof. IPs can be dynamic and you can't ever be sure you have a unique user. Even then, there'd still be traces of the button in your DOM.